# irreducibility of polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$$p(x)=x^9+18x^8+132x^7+501x^6+1011x^5+933x^4+269x^3+906x^2+2529x+1733$$
Is there a way to prove irreducubility of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ different from asking to PARI/GP?

Comment: $1733$ is a prime.

Comment: @Inceptio what can i deduce from this?

Comment: If there was a possibility $p(x)=g(x)h(x)$, We know that $1733$ is a prime. So, $g(x)=(x+1)(x+1)...(x+1)$ and $h(x)=(x+1733)$. But $g(x)h(x) \neq p(x)$. Want me to write the complete proof as an answer?

Comment: @Inceptio: If I understand correctly, with your method we can prove that the polynomial $x^3+3x^2+x+3$ is irreducible. But it isn't.

Comment: @Inceptio i'm not completely convinced: say $g(x),h(x)$ be two factors of $p(x)$. One could have 1733 as constant term, and the other 1, so giving by multiplication the costant term 1733 of $p(x)$

Comment: @P..: Provided some conditions! Called Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: How do you apply Eisenstein's criterion here?

Comment: @LiorB-S: Multiply the whole thing by $3$.

Comment: @Inceptio: But then $3$ divides the leading coefficient, and you can't apply this criterion...

Comment: @LiorB-S: Thanks a lot. I didn't really notice that. Thanks.

Comment: This looks (but I have only experiments, no proof) like one of those polynomials that are irreducible over the rationals, but is reducible modulo each prime.

Comment: This polynomial is probably the one OP is discussing [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/334597/11619). At least it has the prescribed zero (also sprach Mathematica 3.0). AFAICT that also explains the observation made by @AndreasCaranti  - over a finite prime field the two polynomials either split or don't, and you never get more than a sextic extension as their compositum.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Is it true we get a irreducible polynomial if we add a prime to reducible one.?

Comment: @Inceptio. No! The polynomial $x^2+4x$ is reducible. Adding the prime $3$ to it gives us another reducible polynomial $x^2+4x+3=(x+3)(x+1)$. No such simple rule holds.

Answer (score 2):

A starting point: Modulo $3$ the polynomial $p$ takes the form
$$
red_3(p) = x^9-x^3-1\in \mathbb{F}_3[x].
$$
Since raising to $3$ is the frobenius automorphism we have
$$
red_3(p) = (x^3-x-1)^3.
$$
The polynomial $x^3-x-1$ is irreducible modulo three.

From all of this we get that if $p$ factors to a product 
$$
p=p_1\cdots p_r,
$$
with $p_1, \ldots, p_r\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ monic and irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$,
then $r\leq 3$ and the degree of each factor is at least $3$.

Comment: why the last line of your answer implies $p$ irreducible?

Comment: It doesn't. As I wrote in the first line, it's just a starting point...

Comment: ok, thank you for suggestion

Comment: @bateman: This route (reduce modulo a prime) will never prove this polynomial to be irreducible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: True, proves it is irreducible for certain modulo prime.

Comment: @Inceptio. That's not what I said. I specifically said that this polynomial is NOT irreducible modulo ANY prime.

Comment: Yeah! But the proof over modulo works only for few primes. Right?

Comment: No, this method always work. In fact if you choose different primes you get different factorizations, and at the end you will get that the only possibility is that the polynomial is irreducible. For example modulo $11$ gives a factorization type $1^12^4$ which does not fit with the one modulo 3...

Comment: and modulo 7 the factorization type is $3^16^1$. But for these I had to use sage, hence it doesn't qualify as an answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

This polynomial has the element $\alpha^2+\beta$ described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334597/11619) as a root. My answer to that question implies among other things that the minimal polynomial of that element is of degree 9, so this polynomial has to be irreducible.

Comment: Is there any different way? Using the fact that $1733$ is a prime. And other coefficients of $x^n(n \epsilon 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ are divisible by $3$?

Comment: @Inceptio: I'm sure there are other ways, but I don't see a cleaner one. The coefficient of the cubic term, 269, is not divisible by three. Modulo 3 information is already utilized in Lior's answer. That shows that it suffices to exclude the possibility of a cubic factor. May be you can do that by some brute force trick? The constant term of such a factor would have to be $\pm1$ or $\pm 1733$, so there are only those four cases, each with two unknown parameters. Go for it :-)

Comment: Yeah, I always miss a fact. And the cases you're talking about. I assumed $(\pm1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...a_nx^n)(\pm 1733+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+...b_kx^k)=p(x)$. I just need to prove this it is impossible.?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind evaluating $p(x)$ several times and factoring large numbers, you could find $10$ values for $x$ which are separated by more than $2$, for which $p(x)$ is prime (or a unit).  This would imply that $p(x)$ (having degree $9$) is irreducible.

The logic being: If $p(\alpha)$ is prime and if $p(x) = q(x) r(x)$, then $q(\alpha)$ or $r(\alpha)$ must be a unit ($\pm1$).  Given that $q(x), r(x)$ must also have degrees that sum to that of $p(x)$, the number of times they can take the value of a unit is restricted - maximum is two times the degree of $p(x)$, to account for two possible signs for the units.  However, if the $x$ values are separated by more than $2$, then for any of $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ the sign of the unit must be the same, and then there cannot be then more prime values than the degree of $p(x)$.

Here, we have $p(x)$ prime for $x \in \mathrm{A} = \{-16, -10, -3, 0, 3, 6, 14, 17, 28, 39 \}$. (I have omitted values such as $\{-12, -4, -2, -1, 5\}$ which also give primes but are too close to  elements of $\mathrm{A}$, to avoid having to find $19$ prime values).  As these are $10$ values separated by more than $2$, $p(x)$ is irreducible.