# Galois automorphisms and Field extensions

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

> Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+3x-1$ and let $\beta$ be a root of $x^3-x+2$.

I want to show that $\alpha^2+\beta$ has degree $9$. There are many ways to do this, but **I wish to solve the problem by the following line of argument**: using the automorphisms of the normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ might allows us to show that the latter contains at most two cubic subfields, which thus have to be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Can somebody help?

**Edit:** The answer by *Jyrki Lahtonen* in [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334597/degree-of-a-field-extension) goes exactely in that direction, but it is not completely clear to me, and I believe/hope the argument could me made cleaner.

Comment: Funny. The exact same question has been asked here very recently. In two parts even! Here is [part one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/334597/11619) and [part two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/334635/11619). Kudos to you for telling that it is homework! (well, we would have guessed anyway)

Comment: But you're on the right track. I think I found an argument showing that the only non-trivial subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ are the two obvious cubic ones. The normal closure OTOH has no less than six cubic subfields. Each of the conjugates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ also give rise to such a subfield (and they are not the same subfield as only one of the roots is real). My argument (as an answer to part one above) is not complete in its details either.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes, thanks! I edited the post and I tried to explain why it should be unmarked from *duplicate*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Regarding your first comment. Of course it is a homework, as I tagged it, from Number Theory class, though it is not due. In fact I am actually doing it for my own sake. That is why I am interested in this particular solution. Funny though I found a classmate on here!!